# Как проверить, что пользователь подписался после перехода по ссылке на YouTube или Facebook?

Tags: java, android

Пишу игру на Андроид, Хочу сделать так, чтобы после того как пользователь нажал на кнопку и перешел по ссылке(канал You Tube, группа в Facebook) можно было проверить подписался он или нет(давать вознаграждение или нет). Как сделать переход по ссылке - я знаю. А как сделать проверку - нет.

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать только если:

1. Юзер залогинится в нужной соц.сети дав вам доступ к вызовам методов API от его имени.
2. У API нужной соц.сети есть методы для выяснения нужной вам информации

Таким образом без очень большого объёма работ, включающего в себя авторизацию в нужных соц.сетях и изучения их API у вас не выйдет такое реализовать.

Comment: Слышал о WebDriver краем уха. Эта библиотека не поможет?

Comment: @AlexWHITE, это библиотека которая запускает браузер и позволяет им программно управлять. С помощью костылей и крепких слов её можно было бы как-то применить к этой задаче, но это будет совсем не то. Простого способа сделать вам нужное нет - только API использовать

Comment: Спасибо! Зашел в API YouTube, там вроде есть то, что нужно, только осталось разобраться...